# Git workflow for two type product with 80% similarity

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-flow

I have a two type product with 80% basic code (Community Edition & Enterprise Edition). I have a little knowledge about `git-flow` and like it, but I don't know to integrate with my needs.

Some `Enterprise Edition` feature shouldn't be include in `Community Edition` and also some multi language files shouldn't be include in `Community Edition`.

```
 master         
   |         
  / \
 /   \
CE   EE
|     |
tag   tag
```

What Should I do? How to manage repository branch with this structure?

Comment: Does the enterprise edition contain everything in the community edition (not just every feature, every change, line of code, etc. unless explicitly modified for enterprise)? Or are some parts vastly different?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen In most cases, they are similar. In some feature do not even has files like multi language and in some feature, some code comment. Off course maybe in 2% of code has conflict between CE & EE.

Comment: I would not solve this Problem in SCM. I would extract the common behavior into a separate Project/module (in ist own SCM repo) that gets inherited by either "Edition".

Comment: i agree with @TimothyTruckle this is not a good fit for a SCM, this should be handled in code or at runtime or maybe even before in the build.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle @phoet @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Can I consider `Enterpise Edition` as master and create a new branch from master as CE and remove additional feature in this branch?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define, if you want your customer can see code of the `Community Edition` or not.

If guess not, which means you deliver a compiled product of software I would recommend a master branch with everything in it and some compile options to enable or disable a feature.

If yes, so if it's some kind of open or interpreted code, I would recommend a `git submodule` with the common part and two repositories for `Enterprise Edition` and `Community Edition`